Azure App Container and App Gateway - "host name" is not correct
I've implemented a Container App with an Application Gateway on Azure. In the Application Gateway, the "Backend Setting" configuration is set as follows:

"Override with new host name" = "Yes"
"Host name override" = "Pick hostname from backend target"

Using the Application Gateway Public IP, I can correctly visualize the website.
However, when clicking on a link, I receive a "wrong page" error because all relative URLs contain the Container App URL (e.g., https://container-app-name1.orangeglacier-859ee193.italynorth.azurecontainerapps.io) instead of the Application Gateway IP.
I've also tried to print the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] variable and it contains container-app-name1.orangeglacier-859ee193.italynorth.azurecontainerapps.io.
What could be causing this issue and how can I ensure that all relative URLs use the Application Gateway IP?
Thank you!

When the Application Gateway forwards requests to your Container App, the Container App is seeing its own hostname (e.g., container-app-name1.orangeglacier-859ee193.italynorth.azurecontainerapps.io) instead of the hostname of the Application Gateway. This causes your application to generate URLs based on the Container App's hostname rather than the Application Gateway's public IP or hostname.

Thank you @Arko that is the behavior! But how I can solve this problem? Is there a way to use the App Gateway hostname?


Azure App Container and App Gateway - "host name" is not correct

The issue seems to be with the way you declared backend absolute path instead of a relative path because of which client seems to send the requests to another path instead of actual desired IP.

The actual URL need to accessed looks like http://<AppGwIp>/sample/test and you select/click a file called file.txt from browser client but instead of this it responds http://container-app-name1.orangeglacier-859ee193.italynorth.azurecontainerapps.io/sample/test/file.txt .
When this happens, the client now is redirected to the actual site instead of the reverse proxy which is App Gateway.

In your case the backend is Container Apps, as per the MSDoc you can always modify the DNS to point to the App Gateway IP. So, the URL will be validated to be a custom domain for Container Apps and the DNS resolves to the App Gateway Public IP.
For more information on Host Name Preservation check with the document it tells why it's not and recommends you use a custom domain.
To overcome the issues mentioned follow the documentation
Refer:
Azure App Container and App Gateway - "host name" is not correct - Microsoft Q&A by KapilAnanth-MSFT
Azure Application Gateway documentation | Microsoft Learn
Azure Application Gateway HTTP settings configuration | Microsoft Learn
